# Unable to run scala test in intellIJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I cannot make head and tail of what I am supposed to do here. I get this error when trying to run some test in intelliJ. Nothing comes up in intelliJ forums for this issue. Please help.

```
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading 
class file 'CmdLineParser.class'.
Could not access term parsing in package scala.util,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build 
definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` 
to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'CmdLineParser.class' was compiled against 
an incompatible version of scala.util.
(NOTE: It looks like the scala-parser-combinators module is missing; 
try adding a dependency on "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-parser-combinators".
   See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/ for more information.)
```

Community post in IntelliJ: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000704450-Unable-to-run-scala-test-in-intellIJ

Comment: "try adding a dependency" .. and did you? Can you show your `build.sbt`?

Comment: @Suma - I added the scala parser combinators directly into libraries in project structure. No effect. We do not use sbt, we have our own build system. But our code does not use scala parser combinators anywhere.

Comment: CmdLineParser is part of scalacheck - and it used parsers in some older versions (before [this commit](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/commit/2372c618487ec2521276112c68031b9477915491#diff-0638b7cf1d2ebe163392b090460f6627)). Are you using scalacheck? Which version?

Comment: @Suma no i am not.